# Upgrading to Spring cloud 1.0.1 zuul url encoded parameters not working

Tags: spring-cloud, netflix-zuul

We use zuul as an gateway to dispatch incoming requests to services.

When we upgraded from 1.0.0, we noticed two issues, one of which we got a workaround to.

The second issue is that in some of the incoming have encoded uris to deal with special characters in the request, e.g. ....rovi//45846 which needs to be changed to rovi%2F%2F45846 in order to pass in.

So for a rest uri like the following POST http://localhost:8902/contentservice/content/subscriptionPackages/624460160/channels/rovi%252F%252F45846

If I make this request directly to the service, it works correctly.
But if I route it through zuul as POST http://localhost:8765/contentservice/content/subscriptionPackages/624460160/channels/rovi%252F%252F45846 then it disappears.

Now if I take the % out it is passed in and treated as an error in the contentservice when I step through the content service front end controller (off course).

What has changed between spring cloud 1.0.0 to 1.0.1 in the zuul functionality to stop this from working.  As it definitely was working in 1.0.0.

Comment: We have a fix in snapshots.  Waiting on a release.

Answer (score 0):

So the spring cloud team has fixed this in the snapshot releases and you can fixed more detail here
https://github.com/spring-cloud/spring-cloud-netflix/issues/366#issuecomment-106363315